# how do i confirm i'm using yarn link correctly?

Tags: javascript, npm, package, yarnpkg

How can I tell my local linked package is in use rather than from remote? Is it suppose to show up in the dev server of my local package?

Answer (score 24):

If you are linking packageA into your project and wanting to confirm it is working, go to the base dir for the project and type:

```
ls -l node_modules/ | egrep "^l"
```

This will list any linked modules, each will show as:

```
lrwxr-xr-x 1 vagrant vagrant    66 Feb  3 14:39 packageA -> ../../../home/vagrant/.config/yarn/link/packageA
```

Also, if you are using VS Code, links are shown visually, if you scroll down your node_modules dir you will see:

[image]

Comment: Also if you want this command to work for author scoped packages (starting with `@`), you need to use it as `ls -l node_modules/* | egrep "^l"`. The diff is the start sign at the end node_modules.

Comment: [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1722) is related, and an official solution is being discussed.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [yarn link documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/link/), the yarn link uses a local copy of the package.

`This will create a symlink named react-relay/node_modules/react that links to your local copy of the react project.`

Answer (score 1):

On windows I can see linked packages under **C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\link** On linux under
**~/.config/yarn/link**